# Loop through rows until you find a variable and then count the number of rows

Tags: php, mysql

I'm building a rank system, I have many horses and on the horse profiles I want to echo the rank of the horse depending on the amount of wins. 1st, 2nd, 3rd etc.

This is my MySQL table containing the horses, in PHP how would I count the rows to get the rank of the horse?

Here's my table, for instance if I was on "Pauls" profile, how would I echo out that he is in 4th position in the global ranking?

[image]

Comment: How did you define that Paul is in 4th poistion ?

Comment: By my count Nam3 is in 4th position. He has 2 first, 2 second and 2 third. While Paul has 2 first and just 1 third. Do you need to sort it just by column first or also second and third?

Comment: Preferably by wins, and the 2nds/3rds as a fall back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.

```
select h.*, @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rank
from horses h, (SELECT @rownum := 0) r
order by h.first DESC, h.second DESC, h.third DESC
```

2.

```
SELECT * FROM
(
select h.*, @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rank
from horses h, (SELECT @rownum := 0) r
order by h.first DESC, h.second DESC, h.third DESC
) t
WHERE id = 428
```

Comment: This works great and creates a temporary table with the ranks, but how do I then extract the rank depending on the horse's ID?

Comment: you can try the second query

Answer (score 0):

Use Order By on multiple columns according to priority.

```
$sql = "SELECT
@rownum := @rownum + 1 as row_number
FROM    horses
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rownum := 0) r
WHERE name = "Paul"
ORDER BY 
        first ASC,
        second ASC,
        third ASC";
```

now you can obtain the position value from query for any users.

Comment: Shouldn't they all be `DESC`?

Comment: This would mean a horse with 3 'first' but 0 'second' would come up higher than a horse with 2 'first' and 20 'second'.

Comment: this doesn't take into account a person with 5 seconds can be higher as 1 first? Totally depends on how you count it

Comment: So this is great, so say my $varible was "Paul" or Pauls ID, how do I output in PHP his position?

Comment: @Alvi_1987 because the one with the most first places is first, not last.

Answer (score 0):

Two queries to get position of your search record

```
set @name='Paul',@nr = 0,  @namenr = 0;
select @namenr as nr from 
(SELECT @nr:=@nr+1,if(name=@name, @namenr := @nr,@namenr=@namenr),name FROM SOME_TABLE order by first DESC ) subsel where subsel.name = @name;
```

second query will return one record with `nr` column which you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your scoring system, this could be the right solution for you:

Say your 'first' means 3 points, 'second' means 2 points and and 'third' means 1 point.

This way you can calculate what horse has the most points based on the total.

Example:

Paul has 2 'first', 0 'second' and 1 'third', scoring him to 7 points.
Fletcher has 2 'first', no 'second' and no 'third', scoring him to 6 points.

Calculate the sum of all the points and order it by that field, DESC.

## Example query:

```
SELECT (`first`*3)+(`second`*2)+(`third`*1) AS `total_score` FROM `horses` ORDER BY `total_score` DESC
```

## Additional 'rank' field

```
SET @rank=0;
SELECT @rank:=@rank+1 AS `rank`, (`first`*3)+(`second`*2)+(`third`*1) AS `total_score` FROM `horses` ORDER BY `total_score` DESC
```

Comment: This is exactly what I'm going to do, I'm going to add another column in the table with a total "Score", but even when I have that total score for each horses how do I count how many rows down they are after sorted by "Score? using PHP or SQL?

Comment: I updated my answer to add a 'rank' field that you can use (havnt tested it)

Answer (score 0):

With the following query you can have your table, and next to it the rank of each horse:

```
SELECT *,
@curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank
FROM (SELECT @curRank := 0) r, horses
order by first desc, second desc, third desc
```

I am using the `(SELECT @curRank := 0)` to initialize the `curRank` within the query

Answer (score 0):

To get the rank of a *particular* horse, you need only count the number of records that rank above it; sorting by row constructors is a very concise way of accomplishing this:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) + 1
FROM   horses
WHERE  (first, second, third)
     > (SELECT first, second, third FROM horses WHERE id = ?)
```